# Can a compiler optimize out a function preamble in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, decompiling

I am attempting to build a decompiler for x86 executables and was wondering if I can safely assume that function preambles/prologues will remain intact. Is it possible compilers could optimize them out of the assembly?

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it and other people can see.

Comment: They don't just stop at removing the preamble, functions are often removed completely.

Comment: If it's unnecessary, somebody, somewhere, probably has an optimization pass that strips it out.  :-)

Comment: `gcc -O3` and `objdump -S` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, things like leaf functions (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Leaf-Functions.html)) might be optimized, as well as any function that doesn't use any local variables.